# What is React Native WebView alternative for Capacitor/Angular?

Tags: angular, react-native, ionic-framework, capacitor

I need to transform WebView component from React Native to Capacitor/Ionic/Angular:

```
<WebView
   source={{uri: customUri}}
/>
```

Is there some similar option/component with Capacitor which will render component in for example Android WebView?

Comment: Not sure, but since iconic is already a webview i would think you need to use a simple iframe. However with angular if you want to set a source from code you need to go though the dom sanitizer

Answer (score 0):

Probably your are looking for Capacitor Browser plugin. But the problem is, you can't hide the url (I have faced the problem while working with iOS).
[Capacitor Browser Plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser)